# How to change the color of the bottom border of UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I read many threads, but none solved this question in a clear, consistent answer for the latest version of Swift.

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101361/ios7-change-uinavigationbar-border-color)'s top answer suggests `UINavigationBar.appearance().setShadowImage()`. However, such a method does not exist in the latest version of swift.

I **don't want to hide** the bottom border. I just want to **change the color**.

Additionally, it'd be great to be able to change the height, but I know I'm asking too much in one question.

**Edit:** I created a 2x1 pixel image and set it to the shadowImage, but the border remains unchanged:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named: "border.jpg") //in my AppDelegate, for global appearance
```

Here's the image; it's really small: [image: border image]

Comment: The shadow image still exists, you have to do `UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = ...` in Swift

Comment: Does anyone know why auto-complete doesn't show shadowImage? (But it does exist, actually)

Comment: Because it's not accessible via `UINavigationBar.appearance()`.

Comment: @ZGski it is accessible. I just did it, and it works, using your answer.

Comment: My answer utilizes `navigationController?.navigationBar`, not `appearance()`

Answer (score 23):

**SWIFT 2.x :**

Out of convenience, I've extended `UIImage()` to allow me to essentially use it as a color with the code immediately below.

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.0, 0.5)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Next, you'll want to add the following lines to your code to adjust the viewController's `UINavigationBar`'s shadow image, or color in this instance.

```
// Sets Bar's Background Image (Color) //
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.blueColor()), forBarMetrics: .Default)
// Sets Bar's Shadow Image (Color) //
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(UIColor.redColor())
```

---

**SWIFT 3.x / 4.x :**

Extension code:

```
extension UIImage {
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

NavigationBar code:

```
// Sets Bar's Background Image (Color) //
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .blue), for: .default)
// Sets Bar's Shadow Image (Color) //
navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: .red)
```

---

**Edit 1:**

Updated extension code so you can adjust rect size without changing `UIImage` color opacity.

**Edit 2:**

Added Swift 3 + Swift 4 code.

Comment: Do you know , why I change the height/width of your rect to ```0.5```, the color changes?

Comment: @TIMEX, I've update my code so this shouldn't happen anymore

Comment: this definitely works but the shadow image on every view controller inside my app all get the color change.

Comment: @LanceSamaria You'll need to reset the `navigationBar` properties for the `ViewController`s that you don't want to take on the new look because the `NavigationController` is a single instance that contains children `ViewControllers`.

Answer (score 2):

Old UIKit setter methods like `UISomeClass.setSomething(whatIWantToSet)` have been reformulated so that you can directly set them with an `=` sign. So, in my example you would have to use `UISomeClass.something = whatIWantToSet`.

In your case, it's `UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = whatYouWantToSet`.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky solution, but it works with no coding and extensions needed. Just add in StoryBoard under your navigationBar a Progress View and set its color and height to whatever you like. If you want full border also set progress to 1.

[image]

So you will get a proper border for your navigation bar and an option to add progressView at any time as extra bonus.
I know, I know... it's kinda tricky, but programmers should be lazy, no?