# Changing the separator color of UINavigationBar

Tags: swift, uiview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I’m working on a iOS-App based on Xcode’s “*Master-Detail Template*” and want to use custom colors for some of the UI elements.

However, I couldn’t find out how to change the **right separator** of the `UINavigationBar`:

[image]

I’ve already tried to change the `backgroundColor` of `UINavigationBar`, `UINavigationItem` and its `titleView` but without success.

Would be great if someone has a clue.

**EDIT:**
I’ve just noted that viewed in vertical mode, it’s the whole separator that I want to ink?

[image]

Comment: As in here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32222707/4172698

Comment: @Michael Nope — your link provides a solution for changing the color of the bottom separator.

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32222707/4172698) gives you

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func setRightBorderColor(color: UIColor, width: CGFloat) {
        let rightBorderRect = CGRect(x: frame.width, y: 0, width: width, height: frame.height)
        let rightBorderView = UIView(frame: rightBorderRect)
        rightBorderView.backgroundColor = color
        addSubview(rightBorderView)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking – glad you’re trying to help. It did not work. Since I’ve noticed that the whole separator is bright colored if I rotate the iPad (see the edit of my original question), I think that its **not** just the `UINavigationBar` that I want to ink. However, your approach to add a new layer above another one doesn’t seem right for me.